# connection refused to connect with mqtt server

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, flask, mqtt, paho

python paho client couldn't connect with mqtt broker which works tls .  this is my code. i tried many ways but failed. i hope u guys can help

```
from flask import Flask
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl
app = Flask(__name__)




def on_connect(self,client, userdata, rc):
    print("connected")
    self.subscribe('iot/ac')
    self.subscribe('iot/deviceid/+/temperature')
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload.decode())

def iotac(client, userdata, message):
    print(client)
    print("hellooooo:"+ message.payload.decode())
    client.publish('iot/deviceid/dndkj/temperature',"hiii")
def iotk(client, userdata, message):
    print(message.topic)
    print("temperature:"+ message.payload.decode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id="aa", clean_session=True, userdata=None,transport="tcp")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.message_callback_add("iot/ac",iotac)
    client.message_callback_add("iot/deviceid/+/temperature",iotk)
    client.tls_set("ca.crt", tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    client.connect("address",8883)
    client.loop_start()

    app.run()
```

and when i run this i am getting error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Connection refused normally means the broker is not running where you think it is or there is a firewall blocking you

Comment: @hardillb i tried mosquito server running perfectly and there is no firewall. how tls certificates added in this program . i think that's the problem

Comment: When I said where, that can include not listening on the port you think it is. Including the log in the question from the startup of the broker and when the connection request is made may help